# Module not defined error due to import export methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am confused between ES6 import export methods.
I have server.js, routes,js and  SignupModels.js (where mongoose Schema is defined)

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import axios from 'axios';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import routesUrls from './routes.js'
import cors from 'cors';


// app config

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;
dotenv.config()


// middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors())
app.use('/api', routesUrls)


//  API Endpoints
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("hello");
});
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_ACCESS, () => {
    console.log("Database connected")
})

// listensers
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`lilstening on port ${port}`);
})
```

**routes.js**

```
import express, { response } from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
import signUpTemplateCopy from './SignupModels.js'

router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    const  signedUpUser = new signUpTemplateCopy({
        
        fullName: req.body.fullName,
        email: req.body.email,
        lat: req.body.lat,
        lng: req.body.lng        
    })
    signedUpUser.save()
    .then( data => {
        response.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        response.json(err);
    })
})


export default module(router);
```

**SignupModels.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const signUpTemplate = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lat: {
        type: Number,
        required : true
    },
    lng: {
        type: Number,
        required : true
    },
    points: {
        type: Number,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('mytable', signUpTemplate);
```

I am getting this error

```
file:///home/vaibhav/Documents/covid-project/covid-backend/routes.js:5
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
       ^

ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at file:///home/vaibhav/Documents/covid-project/covid-backend/routes.js:5:8
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I guess it's a problem related to how I am importing and exporting the modules and not in making the modules or is it because I am mixing ES6 conventions and older conventions

Comment: In your routes file it should be `export default router;` instead of `export default module(router);`

Comment: I am just thrashing myself now, I didn't even look at it. Thanks a lot